# Is "Work at here" correct?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I don't know which one I should use between: *I work here.* And *I work at here*. Supposing I could say *I work at a school*, why can't I say *I work here*. Or can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here= , , or  this place or position

No preposition is necessary before 'here' in standard English.

I work here= I work  this place.

It is better to use 'I work here'.